# PhpStorm LiveEdit HTML works but CSS doesn't

Tags: google-chrome-extension, phpstorm, liveedit

I just set up LiveEdit in PhpStorm 7.0 and downloaded the Chrome Extension "JetBrains IDE Support" v1.25. I also set up a Javascript Debug run configuration. When I run this configuration and edit an HTML file in PhpStorm the page in my Chrome browser reloads as expected. However, if I edit my CSS file the changes are not reflected in my browser unless I reload the page.

Has anyone else had this issue? I've googled quite a bit but haven't come up with anything. I'm stumped because the HTML edits are working fine...

Comment: Please show how you configured JS Debug run configuration -- maybe you have missed something? What sort of JS libraries/scripts do you use on that page? -- maybe it somehow breaks it. Can you reproduce the same with simple 1 HTML and 1 CSS files in test project? [Live Edit tickets](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=%23{Live+Edit})

Comment: [Issue IDEA-139915](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139915)

Answer (score 9):

It has been a while since this question was asked, but I stumbled over the same problem recently and couldn't find any help on that topic.

After some experimenting, I found that setting the the Live Edit options from Manual to Auto in (ms): solved the problem.

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Live Edit -> toggle "Auto in (ms)" on

[image: PHPStorm Live Edit Settings]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks ...actually i didnt insalled Liveedit plugin and was facing same issue...your help me to think that there should be plugin so that i can see that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It doesn't work when you have stylesheet in external file. It works when you got styles in  tag inside the file that you are debugging.
That's the bug propably.