# PhpStorm + Live Edit, can not see changes made to the attached css-file

Tags: css, phpstorm, liveedit

Good afternoon. I connect to IDE PhpStorm Live Edit, set the extension to Chrome. The draft pick html file in the shortcut menu - "Debug index.html" - everything works, everything seems fine. But I have styles stored in the connected file styles.css, and the changes that I'm doing there is not displayed.  If I am bringing in the project on styles.css - the shortcut menu for css-files, no point "debug". Html-files for this item have. But I found a video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0Db0TTZJa8, on it guy ruled css file and the page immediately visible changes. How can I configure Debugging connected css-file?

There is certainly a perverse method - css file copy of all styles and stuff in the head, then everything works, but I wanted would not be subverted.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem as you described above. Found the answer in another post here on Stackoverflow:  [>>>>Quoted from here<<<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738258/phpstorm-liveedit-html-works-but-css-doesnt)

"It has been a while since this question was asked, but I stumbled over the same problem recently and couldn't find any help on that topic.

After some experimenting, I found that setting the Live Edit options from Manual to Auto in (ms): solved the problem.

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Live Edit -> toggle "Auto in (ms)" on

PHPStorm Live Edit Settings[image]"

Maybe its too late for you, but someone else will hit this post for sure, since it is on top in google :D

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is the same issue as [WEB-11393](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11393)

Problem is caused by changes in Chrome API.

Please check if the problem persists in the PHPStorm 8 EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) with the most recent Live Edit plugin installed