# Phpstorm Live Edit not working with external css and js files

Tags: css, google-chrome, phpstorm, liveedit

Phpstorm Live Edit not working with external css and js files.
But when i change html/css/js code in *.html (*.php) files it is work nice.
Problem only with external files, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

Comment: It was answered before by grAPPfruit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28094448/3997577

Answer (score 10):

Please make sure that '`Update`' in `Settings/Build,Execution,Deployment/Debugger/Live Edit` is set to `'Auto in (ms)`' and `'Restart if hotswap fails`' is enabled. Changes in HTML code are updated in the browser automatically regardless of the selected Update mode; but this is not the case for js and css - in Manual mode, you need to click the Update Application button on the debugger tool window or in the main Run menu, or press cmd+F10 to get page refreshed.

See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/

Comment: Thanks mate! It helped. This should be marked as a correct answer.

Comment: 'auto in (ms)' is missing now

Comment: currently the option is **On changes in (ms)**

Comment: I turn on everything in Live Edit Option, but still dosen't work - PHPStorm 2019,3,2